# Will an Honours year grant me a second degree?

Tags: graduate-school, masters, research-undergraduate

I am about to graduate with a Bachelor’s degree in Biotechnology (Hons). I plan to further my studies with a Masters in Research. I would like to apply for an Honours year in Medical bioscience or related subject at a different university (perhaps in Australia) to gain enough qualifications to pursue an interdisciplinary Masters Research. Will doing the Honours year give me a second degree? And will I be able to even apply for an Hons year of a different major?

Comment: I'm thinking it depends on the specific school and degree program. Maybe contact the appropriate people at the university you are considering.

Comment: What is a Honors year?

Answer (score 1):

In Australia, an Honours is considered a separate degree.  Other countries may have no idea what your Honours is.

Usually, once you have an Honours there is no reason to pursue a masters in the same subject.  However, I do not have specific knowledge of bio/medicine.

As for your eligibility, you need to check with particular universities about their policies.  Probably they will consider your marks (grades).